# Problem when adding Crystal report to tabcontrol in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, tabcontrol

We are dynamically configuring a Crystal report and when we show it in a separate window or dynamically adding reports to a C# WPF StackPanel everything is working as it should.

But when we try to add them as TabItems to a TabControl we get an exception from PresentationFramework saying:

> e.Message = "Specified index is out of
>   range or child at index is null. Do
>   not call this method if
>   VisualChildrenCount returns zero,
>   indicating that the Visual has no
>   children.\r\nParameter name:
>   index\r\nActual value was 0."

How do I avoid this crash so that we can have crystal report in our TabControl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had the same problem when trying to put ComponentArt and Telerik controls inside of a TabControl in Silverlight.  I had to make sure that I didn't try to load any of the components with data unless the tab that was containing those controls was the active one.

I ended up moving the initialization from the silverlight page's load event over to some logic in the Tab Controls SelectionChanged event I believe.

Comment: Thanks man. I made sure that the tab was created and displayed before showing the report. And now it works! =)